# What's the point of running unit tests in random order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing

I noticed the default behavior of `Karma` for my `Angular` builds is to run the `Jasmine` unit tests in random order. What is the benefit of running your tests in random order, vs running them in the same order every time?

Comment: What if your tests only work when run in a specific order? Good or bad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes tests modify state that doesn't get reset for every test run. Maybe a test modifies a global variable that is shared by all tests. Maybe a test writes something to the database and doesn't clean it up when the test is done. These things *shouldn't* happen, but sometimes they do happen.

For example:

```
// Stupid contrived example. Don't ever do this.

let num = 0

it('A', () => {
  expect(num + 1).toEqual(1)
})

it('B', () => {
  num = 10
  expect(num + 2).toEqual(12)
})

it('C', () => {
  expect(num + 3).toEqual(13) // passes if B is run before C, otherwise fails
})
```

This may work fine if you always run test A, then B, then C. But then strange things my happen if you run *only* test C. Because of the changes that test A and B made, C passes when you run them all together. But then you run test C alone and it fails.

And now you are staring at you terminal output dumbfounded muttering "how on earth can test C fail?! It just passed!"

Randomizing the order helps with this a bit. Each test *should* be totally isolated and it shouldn't matter what order they run in. Randomizing them may help uncover this badness.

So, given that the order *shouldn't* matter, then why *not* randomize the order?